# Apache Spark accessing the data in hdfs through cross cluster

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, amazon-emr, databricks

I am running Spark on Amazon EMR whose Public DNS is, lets say, `23.21.40.15`.

Now I am executing my Spark Jar on this cluster & I want to write the output of my Spark Job to other Amazon EMR HDFS whose Public DNS is `29.45.56.72`.

I am able to access my own cluster HDFS i.e. `23.21.40.15` but I am not able to write to the cluster `29.45.56.72`.

- What do I need to do so that my spark job can access cross cluster
  HDFS??
- If possible, can anyone share a sample code for this??

Comment: Can you write out on the first cluster and then use distCp to move the output to the second cluster?

Comment: That is one way which is indirect way I suppose....but what if my destination is second cluster ?? I mean if I want to write it to hdfs of second cluster from 1st cluster ??

Answer (score 1):

When you set the output dir in your spark job you can set the credentials to access it like this:

```
hdfs://username:password@hostname:port/pathToFolder
```

PD: you shouldn't write the IPs of your cluster in a public question ;)

Comment: I wrote the IPs just for sample...they are not real IPs...Any alternate way instead of specifying username & password?? how can I do this if there are 2 Amazon EMR clusters involved ??

Comment: If they are both EMR clusters, then you may be able to setup an IAM role to allow EMR access between them, though in theory it seems like that would already be allowed, but you may also need to expose the ports for the security group to access between the two master's.

Comment: Got it...I created my 2nd cluster in N.California whereas my 1st cluster was in N.Virginia...Now I can access the hdfs...Is there any way to access 2 EMR clusters if they are cross-region i.e. 1 cluster is in N.Virginia & other is in N.California ??

Comment: The AWS VPC implementation does not allow a VPC to extend across regions, but you can interconnect both VPCs for instance http://fortycloud.com/interconnecting-two-aws-vpc-regions/